# FIWARE - Is there some Cryptographic GE or a GE with this kind of functionality?

Tags: fiware, fiware-wilma

I would like to know if there are only the Security GEs exposed in the Fiware catalogue. Specifically, I am interested in one component that can do cryptographic functions, like generate and provide key pairs, encrypt, decrypt, etc.

If the answer is no, how can I suggest/implement one GE for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Security GE implementations in FIWARE focus mostly on authentication/authorization and risk analysis. So I would say, no, there are **no GEs** specifically **offering the functionality you are looking for**.

The official way to become a contributor is to send an e-mail to FIWARE collaboration mailing list. Please check the [FAQ](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/FIWARE_Frequently_Asked_Questions_(FAQ)#How_can_I_become_an_active_contributor_to_the_FIWARE_community.3F) for more information and the e-mail address.

By the way, a component which provides a set of cryptographic functions would probably be considered as a **FIWARE Tool** but not a GE. You can take a look at the existing FIWARE Tools, [here](https://catalogue.fiware.org/tools).

Comment: Thanks. I will see the FAQ and the e-mail address. Related to Fiware tools, I dont think this component should act as a tool, but indeed as a GE that other GEs can use for applications where advanced security is needed.